# Десериализация string в List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Вопрос заключается в следующем.

1. Есть класс `PivotBlock`, который содержит среди всех полей поле `ColumnField`

   ```
   public class PivotBlock
   {
       public string ColumnField { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Происходит сериализация и десериализация этого класса с помощью XmlSerializer. Все отлично
3. Дальше меняется спустя время поле `ColumnField` и класс приобретает вид

   ```
   public class PivotBlock
   {
       public List<string> ColumnField { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Но со стороны клиента приходит старый xml файл, который содержит только одно поле

   ```
   <ColumnField>ProductName</ColumnField>
   ```
4. Проблема заключается в том, что десериализатор ждет это, так поле изменилось на список

   ```
   <ColumnField>
       <string>ProductName</string>
   </ColumnField>
   ```
5. Вопрос: как можно скормить десиализатору старый xml файл с этим полем?

   ```
   <ColumnField>ProductName</ColumnField>
   ```

Может установить атрибут на это поле в классе или еще что-то? Я понимаю, что можно разобрать xml файл, найти эти значение по тэгам и т.д. и т.п., но хочется обойтись малой кровью.

Comment: Уточните: моя правка вопроса была правильной? Или я ошибся в предположении, как выглядел класс ранее. Также уточните, как теперь выглядит xml: должен же быть список элементов - так вот, это список `<ColumnField><string>...</string></ColumnField><ColumnField><string>...</string></ColumnField>` или `<ColumnField><string>...</string><string>...</string></ColumnField>` ?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov раньше клас `PivotBlock` содержал в себе несколько разных полей, включая поле `string ColumnField`, о котором идет речь. И xml файл выглядел `<ColumnField>Значение_поля</ColumnField>`
Теперь я заменил `string` на `List<string>` и xml стал выглядеть так 
`<ColumnField><string>значение</string><string>значение</string></ColumnField>`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Больше я ничего предложить не могу. Используйте атрибут, как указано в моём ответе, и сериализуйте именно с ним: тогда не будет вложенных узлов `<string>` и класс будет годиться и для старого формата, и для нового.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PivotBlock
{
    [XmlElement("ColumnField")]
    public List<string> ColumnField { get; set; }
}
```

В таком виде должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо! Хотел еще поинтересоваться - как сделать так, чтобы можно было и считывать и единое поле и также новые поля, которые в массиве? То есть применить, как я думаю, и этот атрибут и еще атрибут с именем "string"?

Comment: @РамильМухаметшин - то есть одновременно принимать и старый, и новый формат xml?

Comment: @ AlexanderPetrov да, то есть у меня может приходить 
`<ColumnField>ProductName</ColumnField>` - это старый формат
и может приходить новый вариант:
`<ColumnField>
    <string>ProductName</string>
</ColumnField>`